# How to create an object from a file?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, bufferedreader

I've a file with a line that looks like this "Room,home,You are in your home"

I wanna read the file and then create an object (I have created a class called Room), what I wanna do now is like read the line and creat something like this.

Room home = new Room (You are in your home)

I have used bufferedreader and split my words and put them in an ArrayList but it just doesn't look right. I need help cuz I don't know how to continue.

```
BufferedReader myfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(thefile));
                String line = thefile.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                String[] array = line.split(",");
                line = file.readLine();}
```

Comment: You'll likely need a loop (with lines 2 and 3) to read all the entries. You'd use the values in `array` to construct what you want.

Comment: I actually have a loop since I have more lines to read in my actual code but I cut that part out because I only needed to know how I can turn this into an object. I will edit it, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Basically, assuming your data in the file is consistent, you can use `array[0]` to determine the object type (via some factory method or switch statement), and `array[2]` as the data you are passing to that object. There's not really a way to automatically name your variable based on the `home` in `array[1]`, though you could store it in a `Map` that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should look like this:

```
array = ["Room", "home", "You are in your home"]
```

However. You can not run something like this:

```
array[0] array[1] = new array[0](array[2]);
```

Therefor you should use some conditions to eventually add more places.

```
if (array[0].equals("Room") {
    Room room1 = new Room(array[2]);
}
```

Or maybe create it as a switch:

```
switch(array[0]) {
    case "Room": ...
    case "Staircase": ...
    ...
}
```

My advice would be to use a class called Room to store aditional information (just like "home") as description.
As @Rogue said: There is no "clean" way use "home" as a name for a variable.

Comment: I have a class called Room, but how do I do it? I mean what about the object and wdym by storing?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
class Test{
public static void test( )throws ParseException {
    String line =  "Room,home,You are in your home";

    String parts[] = line.split(",");
    String objectType = parts[0];
    String objectName = parts[1];
    String objectParameter = parts[2];

    Map<String, Room> roomMap;
    if(objectType.equals("Room")){
        roomMap = new HashMap<>();
        roomMap.put(objectName, new Room(objectParameter));
        System.out.println(roomMap.get(objectName).description);
    }



}
```

}

```
class Room{
public String description;

public Room(String description){
    this.description = description;
}
```

}